# What is the preview box of Google called?

Tags: seo

[image]

Tell me what is the red box and how to get it shown on Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are Featured snippets.

In your screenshot at the bottom red line you can click on the link that says [About Featured snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325?hl=en)
 which will take you to a Google page which explains them more. That page goes on to say the following:

> **How can I mark my page as a featured snippet?**
>
> You can't. Google systems determine whether a page would make a good featured snippet for a user's search request, and if so, elevates it.

Comment: Wow. I didn't see that small footer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something you can get to work automagically. Google will check your content and match it with the keyword. If they see a fit for it to be *featured* as the most relevant search result, they will do so.

So, to answer your question: this is called the `Featured Snippet`.